# apache nifi 1.7.1 restart issue on windows machine

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using apache nifi on a Apache hadoop cluster and when i try to start the run-start.sh file i get below error.

environment: WINDOWS

```
2018-08-23 20:00:31,856 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file D:\NIFI\nifi-1.7.1-bin\nifi-1.7.1\bin\.
.\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-08-23 20:00:31,866 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file D:\NIFI\nifi-1.7.1-bin\nifi-1.7.1\bi
n\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-08-23 20:00:31,879 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 9888
```

and unable to connect from front. this happen when i shut down and try to reconnect again. i generally stopping server using ctrl+_c on windows.

kindly help

Comment: The output you pasted does not include any errors. The bootstrap process is launched. Check `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` for the application log to see what is happening.

Comment: hi @Andy thanks for your reply ... i waited for some time and it started working ...looks like this is issue with NIFI...

Comment: We're happy to help you diagnose the issue but you haven't provided sufficient information to do that. Please provide the contents of the application log. If you are running this by double-clicking the `.bat` file and then the Command Prompt window closes, that would explain it. You need to have a long-running Command Prompt and type the command to start NiFi in it. See [Command Prompt Introduction](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/) for more information.

Comment: If it's just that NiFi takes some time to start, that is because of the NAR loading process. On a standard modern laptop, the initial boot time is about 18 - 25 seconds. You will see in the app log these messages when NiFi is ready:

`2018-08-21 13:05:49,751 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Flow loaded successfully.`

Comment: `2018-08-21 13:05:49,752 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:`
`2018-08-21 13:05:49,753 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer https://node1.nifi.apache.org:9443/nifi`
`2018-08-21 13:05:49,755 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap`
`2018-08-21 13:05:49,759 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Controller initialization took 49148507351 nanoseconds (49 seconds).`